# « Arsenal » signifiant « répertoire »

Tags: traduction, anglais, synonymes

> With Octave, we have an arsenal of functionalities that enable us to
>   retrieve information about the variables.

Dans ce contexte « arsenal » signifie « répertoire », en anglais. En français, « arsenal » peut-il aussi être employé comme un synonyme de « répertoire » ? La traduction suivante est-elle par conséquent légitime ?

> Avec Octave, nous disposons d'un arsenal de fonctionnalités qui nous permettent de récupérer des informations sur les variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arsenal* se traduit par arsenal puisqu'il s'agit du même mot avec la même signification:  au sens propre un dépôt d'armes, et au sens figuré ici, une collection, un ensemble d'outils. En revanche, répertoire n'est pas très adapté ici.

Comment: _Catalogue_ me semble plus approprié que _répertoire_, si on veut éviter _arsenal_.